Create 3D Spiral Carousel
I want to recreate 3d spiral carousel that looks like “rotating stairs” from this website. So far i succefully to create rotating stairs shape with this code :
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { type MutableRefObject, useRef } from 'react'
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Image, type ImageProps, useScroll } from '@react-three/drei'
import { easing } from 'maath'
import './3d-util'

export function Carousel({ radius = 2, count = 8 }) {
  const groupRef: MutableRefObject<THREE.Group | null> = useRef(null)
  const scroll = useScroll()

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (groupRef.current) {
      groupRef.current.rotation.y = scroll.offset * (Math.PI * 2)
    }

    state.events.update?.()
    state.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
  })

  return (
    <group ref={groupRef}>
      {Array.from({ length: count }, (_, i) => (
        <Card
          key={i}
          url={i === 0 ? '/images/test.png' : '/images/og-image.png'}
          position={[
            -Math.sin((i / count) * Math.PI * 2) * radius,
            -0.2 * i,
            Math.cos((i / count) * Math.PI * 2) * radius,
          ]}
          rotation={[0, -(i / count) * Math.PI * 2, 0]}
        />
      ))}
    </group>
  )
}

export function Card({ url, ...props }: ImageProps & { url: string }) {
  const ref = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null)

  useFrame((_state, delta) => {
    easing.damp3(ref.current!.scale, 1.2, 0.1, delta)
    easing.damp(ref.current!.material, 'radius', 0.1, 0.2, delta)
  })

  return (
    <Image ref={ref} url={url} transparent side={THREE.DoubleSide} {...props}>
      <bentPlaneGeometry args={[0.1, 1, 1, 20, 20]} />
    </Image>
  )
}

but there something i cant replicate:

I cant replicate scroll based rotation and positioning
Currently my code just rotate the y angle but cannot make the card at the right position

I want to replicate their rotating interaction which is the images/card moving to the right and going to up like rotating stairs. how can i do this? is there any example that looks like my specifications? thank you
I want to make sure my carousel :

Can be rotating and move to the right and going up like rotating stairs
Can be perfectly placed when item is active

What i've been trying so far is to create some basic rotating and positioning for each item, but cannot perfectly placed like this image which is active item always placed at the center of the spiral
